# Trouble running Python script with crontab on macOS using Anaconda3

Tags: python, bash, macos, cron

Having some trouble with crontab here, I'm not experienced with bash.

I have a basic python script on my desktop.

```
#I'm not sure if I need to shebang here.
with open('hi.txt', 'a') as file:
file.write("Woo")
```

I've tried exporting environment variables in my crontab, and I know I am pointing crontab to the correct directory based on feedback in my mail folder. I believe my problem is I don't know how to tell the interpreter to execute the file using anaconda3.

Crontab:

```
PATH=/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOME=/Users/josephwright/

*/1 * * * * /anaconda3/bin/python3 /Users/josephwright/Desktop/cron/print.py
```

I was getting these errors in my mail folder earlier which lead me to believe the problem is I don't know how to tell bash to execute the file using anaconda3:

```
/bin/sh: /Users/josephwright/Desktop/cron/print.py: /usr/local/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Or

```
/Users/josephwright/Desktop/cron/print.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/josephwright/Desktop/cron/print.py: line 2: `with open('hi.txt', 'a') as file:'
```

With the crontab above, I am no longer getting errors in my mail folder, but I am not getting the text output on the text file in the same directory as my python script. If it's not sending logs to my mail folder, how can I view the log to troubleshoot in the future?

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using wrong python version with your code

Comment: What do you mean use python3? I updated my cronjob above to reflect what I thought you meant.

Comment: @saleh could you be more specific with whats wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have the Anaconda code anchored at the absolute path */anaconda3*? That is extremely unlikely. It should be relative to your home directory. So it is extremely unlikely that your `PATH=/anaconda3/bin:...` entry in your crontab file is doing anything useful.

> ## I'm not sure if I need to shebang here.

A shell script should always have a `!#` (shebang) line. Without that line the script will normally be evaluated by */bin/sh* for legacy compatibility reasons. And that is why your are getting those syntax errors.

If you fix the `PATH` definition it should be sufficient to change the invocation line to something like

`*/1 * * * * python3 cron/print.py`

Comment: _which python_ returns _/anaconda3/bin/python_.  It looks like when Anaconda is installed its at the root.  Should I also shebang my script with !# /anaconda3/bin/python?  I can't try myself until tomorrow.  What does it mean for a script to be evaluated by /bin/sh? As in, bash will read it as a .sh file?  I read my crontab should have the full path to the version of python I want to run, so it should be * * * * * /anaconda3/bin/python /my/directory?  Thanks Kurtis!

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, @jwright. Your environment is weird. Anaconda python environments should always be relative to your home directory. And your home directory should never be `/`. Even if you are logged in as the `root` user. A script without a `#!` line will normally be evaluated by `/bin/sh` for compatibility with UNIX implementations that predate support for the `#!` mechanism.

Comment: What does `echo $HOME` output?

Comment: 'echo $HOME' outputs '/Users/josephwright'. Do you think I installed it incorrectly? Would it be worth uninstalling anaconda? I'm not sure if it will make my life easier in the long run. So if a script is normally evaluated by '/bin/sh', in my case should it be evaluated by  '/directory/to/python' instead?

Comment: I should have been more clear. Your crontab entry said to run */anaconda3/bin/python3*. Which makes no sense if your `HOME` is */Users/josephwright*. You can install Anaconda anywhere. I happen to have it installed at */Users/krader/conda* (note the lack of a `ana` prefix). But it is relative to my home directory. You shouldn't be installing it relative to the root directory.

Comment: You also say "I am not getting the text output on the text file in the same directory as my python script.". To which I reply, of course not. The PWD of your python program when from via a crontab entry is your home directory unless you explicitly change the directory via `cd` or `chdir()`. So, given the example in your question, the *hi.txt* file should be in your home directory.